# Open few files from a file list in tabs of vim editor

Tags: bash, unix, vim

I have a file that contains a list of several unix locations. for example i have a file:

```
list.list
```

that contains the following text:

```
helloworld.c
hello world1.c
test/folder/some_file.vs
lastfile/last.py
```

I want to open each file from that list, automatically, in different vim tabs.
Is there a way to do that?

thanks

Comment: Command [`gf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#gf) opens one file under cursor; [`Ctrl-W gf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#CTRL-W_gf) opens a new tab. To open all files write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well I researched a bit and found a quick way to do it from the terminal

`p[N]` Open N tab pages.  When N is omitted, open one tab page for each file.
`cat` to display list of file
and opened them all using

```
`gvim -p `cat list.list`
```